# Android: How to transaction from single button to multiple fragments' navigators?

Tags: android, navigation, fragment

I have a activity show as follows

[fragments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBl1a.jpg)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmwdw.jpg)

in short, there are two fragments in a activity, I can click a button to change fragmentA, but I don't know how to change fragmentB at the same time.

if I use fragmentB's class name, android-studio throw 'com.android.ui.leakagedetector.NormalFragment' is not an enclosing class'
['com.android.ui.leakagedetector.NormalFragment' is not an enclosing class'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVbeB.png)

if I use
NavHostFragment.findNavController(getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_center_fragment_content)).navigate(R.id.action_NormalFragment_to_SettingFragment);
then run app, it will collapse and throw exception：
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getView()' on a null object reference
[null object reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge1X7.png)

Please give me some advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a way to make it work,

```
            NavHostFragment.findNavController(BottomNormalFragment.this).navigate(R.id.action_BottomNormalFragment_to_BottomReturnFragment);
            NavHostFragment.findNavController(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_center_fragment_content)).navigate(R.id.action_NormalFragment_to_SettingFragment);
```

[before click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9S3v.jpg)

[after click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT65Y.jpg)

Both of fragments' next views are blank for now.
At least, it dosen't collapse.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two fragments , and you want to switch on click of single button , then you can change using flag . for that you need to create one flag as `int flag = 0` so when it will be 0 , you will navigate to fragment action_bottom_normal and then you will change it to 1 . After navigation next time you have value 1 so you will navigate to action_normal_fragment and flag value will be 0 like this.

```
settingsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (flag == 0){
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(R.id.action_bottom_normal);
                flag = 1;
            } else {
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(R.id.action_normal_fragment);
                flag = 0;
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answering. But Main problem is fragmentBottom can not access fragmentCenter.